# Python/Pandas: How to quickly pivot datetimeindex on date and time?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, numpy, pandas, cython

I have a huge pandas timeseries which looks like:

```
2011-02-18 08:05:00-05:00    94.00
2011-02-18 08:10:00-05:00    94.75
2011-02-18 08:15:00-05:00    94.00
2011-02-18 08:20:00-05:00    94.25
2011-02-18 08:25:00-05:00    93.25
2011-02-18 08:30:00-05:00    93.25
2011-02-18 08:35:00-05:00    94.00
2011-02-18 08:40:00-05:00    93.75
2011-02-18 08:45:00-05:00    93.50
2011-02-18 08:50:00-05:00    93.25
2011-02-18 08:55:00-05:00    93.00
2011-02-18 09:00:00-05:00    92.75
2011-02-18 09:05:00-05:00    91.75
2011-02-18 09:10:00-05:00    91.50
2011-02-18 09:15:00-05:00    91.75
```

but it starts in 1999 and goes all the way to 2015.

Operations on this timeseries are really slow, a few seconds is typical (which is slow for me).

How could I pivot the timeseries so that the index is composed of individual dates and the columns are times?

I think the best way is to transform the timeseries into a dataframe, then add a date column (ts.index.date) then add a time column (ts.index.time) and doing a pandas.pivot.

The problem is that creating the date column and the time column is really slow, what is a fast way to create the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try pandas pivot().

s = your series name

```
pd.pivot(index=s.index.date,columns=s.index.time,values=s)
```